# How do I use the new "Ubuntu Font Family" in older releases?

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

I want to use the new Ubuntu fonts that are default in Maverick in Lucid. Where to get it and how to install it?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The Ubuntu Font Family packages are being inserted into order (still supported) releases of Ubuntu as they are released.  As of February 2011, those older releases are:

- Ubuntu **10.10** *Maverick*
- Ubuntu **10.04 LTS** *Lucid*
- Ubuntu **09.10** *Karmic*
- Ubuntu **08.04 LTS** *Hardy*

If you have software updates enabled then you should be able to select the package and install it from the **Ubuntu Software Centre** or using:

- `sudo apt-get install ttf-ubuntu-font-family`

For more details on the process (or to help validate that new releases are suitable for backporting as Stable Release Updates), see:

- [bug #650889](http://launchpad.net/bugs/650889) *Ubuntu Font Family would be valuable for older releases*
- [bug #709980](http://launchpad.net/bugs/709980) *SRU ubuntu-font-family 0.70.1 for all*

Answer (score 0):

Another source is http://font.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: For Ubuntu-based machines, please use the `ttf-ubuntu-font-family` packages in the archives.  Using the archive means that the package can automatically be updated with new features, bug-fixes, and expanded language/style coverage.

Comment: @sladen You may want to post that as a separate answer, rather than as a comment to this answer.