# What is the difference between the ubuntu and ubuntu beta font? Is it worth using?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

Is there a way to install the new Ubuntu font to be used throughout Ubuntu? What is the difference with the 3 fonts: Ubuntu, Ubuntu Title, and Ubuntu beta?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using Maverick, the Ubuntu font should be installed. To use it as a UI font (in case you've upgraded and it's not already set), go to System > Preferences > Appearance > Fonts, and set it as the font to be used for the items of your choice.

UbuntuBeta was the name of the pre-release font that was initially [made available](http://design.canonical.com/2010/07/the-ubuntu-font/) to Ubuntu members for testing, and later to other interested groups. You should avoid using it at this point if it's somehow present together with the "Ubuntu" font on your system.

[Ubuntu Title](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTitle) is the font used for the old Ubuntu logo.

Comment: The font is available in hardy,karmic and lucid-updates too (and of course natty and newer).

Answer (score 4):

The [Ubuntu Font Family](http://font.ubuntu.com)'s final name is "Ubuntu". ([See this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5811/what-is-the-name-of-the-new-ubuntu-font))

- "Ubuntu Beta" is the name of  the font during testing, you can safely remove it.
- "Ubuntu Title" is likely the font from the `ttf-ubuntu-title` package and is an older font in the style of the older deprecated Ubuntu logo.

Comment: So why is it this site uses `font-family: "Ubuntu Beta",UbuntuBeta,Ubuntu,"Bitstream Vera Sans","DejaVu Sans",Tahoma,sans-serif;`? I think it was part of an official recommendation by Canonical...

Comment: @badp Please report this on meta and tag it design, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. **Ubuntu Title** (package `ttf-ubuntu-title`) was the logo typeface between 2004–2010.
2. **Ubuntu** (package `ttf-ubuntu-font-family`) is a typeface under development during 2010–2011 and beyond.  This forms the logotype used for **ubuntu** and **CANONICAL** from 2010 onwards (Ubuntu 10.04 and above)
3. **UbuntuBeta** (package `ttf-ubuntu-font-family`) is used to denote parts of the Ubuntu Font Family that are still in development and not quite ready.  This marks it clear to the user that these are works-in-progress and ensures that they have to be explicitly selected and chosen by the user.

Unless you are involved with the early beta-testing and development process (which of course, you are most welcome to) then I would not recommend attempting to use any versions marked "UbuntuBeta".  The latest *stable* version of the Ubuntu Font Family (`ttf-ubuntu-font-family`) is already available in all supported versions of Ubuntu.  See:

- [Question #5097](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5097/how-do-i-use-the-new-ubuntu-font-family-in-older-releases) *How do I use the new “Ubuntu Font Family” in older releases?*

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Beta is Ubuntu (if you are now running 10.10).  Ubuntu Title is font that was used for the original Ubuntu logo.

If you are using 10.10 as a fresh install the default font is Ubuntu.  Else under **Appearance Preferences > Fonts>** you can set it there.

You may have to install the font `sudo apt-get install ttf-ubuntu-font-family`

I personally enjoy the new font.